# Tkinter/Pillow - How to make (0, 0) in the same place as in Pillow

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So I was trying to figure out who my coordinates were messed up when adding text to an image using canvas coordinates , until I noticed that (0, 0) is off:[image]

How would I put the origin of the canvas in the same place as Pillow does(or at least account for this when adding the text)?

```
class PictureWindow(tk.Toplevel):
def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.x = self.y = 0
    self.rect = None
    self.tex = None
    self.start_x = None
    self.start_y = None
    
    
    image = Image.open(file)
    smaller_image = image.resize((round(image.size[0]/2), round(image.size[1]/2)))
                        
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(smaller_image)
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=img.width(), height=img.height())
    
    self.canvas.img = img 
    self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor=tk.NW)
    self.canvas.pack(expand=True)
    self.canvas.create_text((0, 0), text="(0, 0)", fill=self._from_rgb((225, 225, 225)))
    self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_button_press)
    self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move_press)
    self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_button_release)
    
    self.finished = tk.Button(self, text="Add Watermark", command=self.Watermark)
    self.finished.pack()
    self.go_back = tk.Button(self, text="Go back to change settings", command=self.go_away)
    self.go_back.pack()
    
def _from_rgb(self, rgb):
    r, g, b = rgb
    return f'#{r:02x}{g:02x}{b:02x}'

def go_away(self):
    self.withdraw()
    
def on_button_press(self, event):
    
    self.start_x = event.x
    self.start_y = event.y
    
    
    self.canvas.delete(self.tex)
    self.tex = None 
    
    
    
    if not self.rect:
        self.rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, 1, 1, fill=self._from_rgb((249, 0, 0)), stipple='gray12')
        
        
        

def on_move_press(self, event):

    self.curX, self.curY = (event.x, event.y)
    self.text_x = ((self.start_x + self.curX) / 2) 
    self.text_y = ((self.start_y + self.curY) / 2) 
    
    
    self.canvas.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, self.curX, self.curY)
    
    



def on_button_release(self, event):
    font_preview_size = int(font_size)
    font_preview_almost = (font_preview_size)
    font_preview = int(font_preview_almost)
    
    if not self.tex:
        self.tex = self.canvas.create_text((self.text_x, self.text_y), text=watermark_text, font=('Gotham Medium', font_preview), fill=self._from_rgb((color)))
        

    
def Watermark(self): 
    
    
    
    self.font_size_var = font_size
    Font_Size = int(self.font_size_var) 
    

    A = alpha 
        
    
        
    R = int(color[0])
    B = int(color[1])
    G = int(color[2])

    img = Image.open(file).convert("RGBA")
    img_down = img.resize((int(img.width/2), int(img.height/2)), resample=Image.NEAREST)
    
    img_down.x, img_down.y = img_down.size 
    txt = Image.new('RGBA', img_down.size, (225,225,225,0))

    
    if custom_font == "yes":
        font = ImageFont.truetype(font_file, Font_Size)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)
        text = watermark_text
        
        
        
    if custom_font == "no": 
        font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', Font_Size)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)
        text = watermark_text
    
    
    self.final_x = self.canvas.canvasx(self.text_x)
    self.final_y = self.canvas.canvasx(self.text_x)
    
    
    
    draw.text((self.final_x, self.final_y), text, font=font, fill=(R, G, B, A))
    
    
    
    comp = Image.alpha_composite(img_down, txt)
    
    img_up = comp.resize((int(comp.width*2), int(comp.height*2)), resample=Image.NEAREST)
    
    img_up.save(save_file)
    img_up.show()
```

p.s. if anyone knows why when the pillow text alpha is set to 0, the text is never added, please let me know!

Comment: Read up on the `anchor` option when adding images to a canvas.

Comment: When text `alpha` is set to 0, it means the text is completely transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just post Bryan Oakley's comment as an answer. Pillow has an anchor option and all I needed to do was set it to mm